# React-Native app is not Up to Date

Tags: react-native

I'm modifying the JS files, but the generated APK is not up to date and my modifications don't show. Only if I use reload my modifications show up.

Is this normal?

I'm using windows.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, In normal mode you have to manually reload the changes every time you change the code. You can turn on Hot Reloading in the app setting popup (which you can open with Ctrl+M on Android and Cmd+D on iOS) to auto reload changes as soon as you save the file